# Charset encoding problem in webservices called from Biztalk

Tags: encoding, biztalk, character-encoding

I have a problem occurring when Biztalk calls SOAP web services. The web services from one specific system seems to not always include a "charset" attribute in the Content-Type response header. In the cases where this is missing, the charset is interpreted as Windows-1252 encoding instead of UTF-8.

The response from the web servcie is actually UTF-8 encoded even when the "charset" attribute is missing. So my question is if it's somehow possible to tell Biztalk that UTF-8 should be used as default charset when no charset is specified in the HTTP response headers from the service.

Just to specify further:
If the following header is returned from the web service, Biztalk interprets the charset correctly:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

However when the charset part is missing, Biztalk falls back on Windows-1252 encoding and some international characters are garbled:

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

I know that the simplest solution would be to fix the web service to always return the UTF-8 charset attribute, but sadly we have no control over the services and the vendor will not release a fix for this anytime soon.

Another fix we have attempted is to use rewriting in IIS to rewrite the response header. This works fine unless when the services returns a large amount of data. In that case IIS will used chunked encoding, and the rewrite engine seems to double chunk-encode the output from the web service, rendering the resulting output broken.

The only solution I had working so far is to use an Apache web server as a proxy, and rewrite the header with Apache. This works, but since it introduces extra overhead and is quite hackish we would rather prefer to fix the problem at an existing end-point. Currently the Biztalk end is the only one we have access to make changes on.

I hope anyone can help me on this.

Comment: As others have commented I am surprised that BTS treats it as 1252, as it normally defaults to UTF-8. can you elaborate on how and where you see the issue? usually BTS can be guided around the encoding to use/assume through the XMLNORM properties, but exactly how that applies to your scenario does depend on the details i.e. the message flow

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use an Encoding Transcoder Custom Pipeline Component in the receive pipeline. This is, IMHO, better than hosting a separate proxy in a third-party server. But you are right, solving the problem at its root would be better if you can have a hand on the external web service.

Such a composent can be found there:
http://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/category/pipeline-components/

Comment: I was really hoping there was a setting where a default encoding could be specified. The problem is not the encoding of the source data; it does not need any transcoding since it's already UTF-8. We only need to tell Biztalk that it should assume the XML is UTF-8 encoded if no encoding is specified in the HTTP response headers from the web service.

Comment: As far as I know, BizTalk *does* assume UTF-8 encoding, in the absence of otherwize explicit mention. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559602(BTS.20).aspx. If you definitely observe windows-1252 input, this means it has been explicitly albeit incorrectly specified by the web service. In which case, you need a solution similar to m'y suggestion...

Comment: I have tested the web service using SoapUI and also done a packet capture using Wireshark, and the output from the Webservice definitively is UTF-8 in both cases. The only difference seems to be the charset property missing in the Content-Type header.

Comment: The output from Biztalk looks like UTF-8 parsed as Win-1252 (I have seen the result of this numerous times). This means that common norwegian chars like æ, ø and å are outputted as two chars (the two UTF-8 bytes mapped to the Win-1252 codepage).

Comment: Can you check if this is happening in the adapter or during pipeline processing? Perhaps, temporarily set the pipeline to PassThruReceive to confirm. I don't think the Disassembler is at fault here. Probably, in the absence of charset in the response header, the adapter might be doing the wrong thing. In that case, the solution is trickier and potentially involves injecting a custom behaviour or configuring a custom WCF binding. You're using WCF right?